# HAVING COUNT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT e.user_id
FROM event e
GROUP BY e.user_id
HAVING COUNT(e.action = 'like') = 0 AND COUNT(e.action = 'comment') = 0
```

I want to select the user ids that do not have any action in 'like' and 'comment'. However, seems the last line of the code does not work. Could someone suggest some modification? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Where` Clause & `NOT IN` Operator.

```
SELECT e.user_id
FROM event e
Where Not e.action IN ('like', 'comment')
```